# What is the purpose of foundation.dart in Writing and Reading Files using path_provider plugin?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to understand how to read and write data on text files using [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) plugin.

I've read an example on how to use it on Flutter from [here](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/). Then I saw this line of code which I don't understand:

```
import "package:flutter/foundation.dart";
```

I tried to comment it out from the code and ran "flutter run":

```
//import "package:flutter/foundation.dart";
```

And to my surprise, it ran perfectly. Although it raised some errors like:

```
E/DartVM  (23127): 'dart:core/runtime/libintegers.dart': error: Unexpected tag 0 (Nothing) in ?, expected expression
E/DartVM  (23127): ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/compiler/intrinsifier.cc: 153: error: Intrinsifier failed to find method ~ in class _Smi
```

and

```
E/DartVM  (23237): 'dart:typed_data': error: Unexpected tag 15 (DirectPropertyGet) in ?, expected type
E/DartVM  (23237): ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/compiler/intrinsifier.cc: 153: error: Intrinsifier failed to find method get:x in class _Float32x4
```

But it ran well. I don't know why. When should I use it? What method from the code did the foundation.dart was used?

I would appreciate any kind of enlightment. Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]

I think I understand why foundation library was used in the example code. Maybe because the example code used the "required" constant from the foundation library.